# Laravel relationship with one-to-one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following `users` table structure:

```
id
email 
....
status // foreign key from tbl_status
```

Now in my `tbl_status`:

```
id
name
description
```

Now I would like to create a relationship such that if I have a status of 1 in the `users` table I would like to get its name. I have tried:

In my `User` model:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'status'
    ];

    public function userstatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Status', 'id', 'status');
    }
}
```

In the `Status` model:

```
class Status extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description'
    ];
}
```

When fetching records via...

```
return User::with("userstatus")->paginate(10);
```

...it always returns the status as `null` even though each user has a default status of 1 and the status table has an ID of 1 with a value.

Comment: Add user_id column to tbl_status table with foreign key constraint referencing users id column

Comment: Thanks ive  updated and now it works. Is it possible to get just the name alone since ot returns an entire array of status data that is get only the name alone

Comment: the reason for the status table is to have consistent data. Eg when creating a user having a foreign key of 0 and just displaying the name in the frontend means whoever is creating a user saves an id 0 meaning active and later when the the client may want to change the name active to active user he will just update the status table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This relationship is backwards. Placing the `status` foreign key on the `users` table creates the following relationships:

- `User` belongs to `Status`
- `Status` has many `User`s

However, the question shows a `hasOne()` relation on the `User` model for `userstatuses()`. For this to work, `tbl_status` will need a `user_id` field, but this means that a `Status` *can only belong to one* `User`.

Instead, the correct relation for `userstatus()` on `User` should be `belongsTo()`:

```
public function userstatus() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Status::class, 'status'); 
}
```

Then we can use the proper relations on the `User` model:

```
$user = User::with('userstatus')->find(1); 
$user->status;                 // 1  (foreign key ID)
$user->userstatus->name;       // "status name"
$user->userstatus->description // "This is the status description."
```

Comment: This is a good answer. You can also deal with selection of certain fields in the relationship as well.

Comment: doesnt belongsTo means that a user can have multiple statuses but hasOne Means that the user has only one status?

Comment: Nope. User has a foreign key that references id on status. A user can be assigned a status at a time but a status can be assigned to different users.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI, no `hasMany()` means the user can have multiple statuses. We use `belongsTo()` here to describe *which* status a user currently belongs in.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI this is a better answer than the one I gave. Explains more and yes i missed the relationship bit.

Comment: @Mena marked it as correct then. Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it will be to add a user_id column that references the users id column as the foreign key instead of status. That should fix it.

Comment: it surely fixes the problem but is it possible to get only one variable from the status table eg: get only name alone without the other variables

Comment: Yes you can get the name alone. In your view try something like user->userstatus->name

Comment: Marked the answer too. am returning json data does it mean that ill now have again to do foreach statement to break it down